# SwiftUI NavigationLink not pushing view programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos, watchos-6

I am having issues with pushing a view in SwiftUI by using a `NavigationLink`.

Currently I have it set up so that a binding boolean is set to "true" depending on whether a login was successful or not. However, when I run the code, the view is not pushed despite the boolean being successfully changed.

I am using Swift 5 and developing on WatchOS 6.2, which does NOT require the `NavigationLink` to be nested in a `NavigationView` since it's not supported.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Login: View {
    @State var pushErrorView = false
    @State var pushActivityView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action:
            {
                self.login()
            }) {
                Text("Log In")
            }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: PopupMessage(message: "Login Error"), isActive: self.$pushErrorView) {
                EmptyView()
            }.hidden()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: ActivityView(), isActive: self.$pushActivityView) {
              EmptyView()
            }.hidden()
        }
    }
    
    private func login(){         
        if loginSuccess() {
             self.pushActivityView = true                    
        }
        else {
             self.pushErrorView = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `.hidden()` for your NavigationLinks. If they only have `EmptyView()` as a body they won't be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / watchOS 6.2 on replicated code (due to absent dependent components).

```
struct Login: View {
    @State var pushErrorView = false
    @State var pushNextView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action:
            {
                self.login()
            }) {
                Text("Log In")
            }.background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Group {
                    if pushErrorView { PopupMessage(message: "Login Error") }
                    else { ActivityView() }
                }, isActive: self.$pushNextView) { EmptyView() }
            )
        }
    }

    private func login(){
         self.pushErrorView = !loginSuccess()
         self.pushNextView = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
NavigationLink(destination: YourSecondView(), isActive: $areYouGoingToSecondView) { 
    EmptyView() 
}
```

No `.hidden()` is needed

Comment: Removing the .hidden() still yields the same result